# Add missing item to another file

Tags: excel, vba

**Copy missing data from one file to another.**

I have 2 Excel files and I want to copy missing data from one file to another. I have a code that copies only one column B only. But I want to copy its related columns A, B, and C. How to change the code

```
Sub test1()
    Dim fn As String, cn As Object, rs As Object
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Godown Stock.xlsm"   '<--- alter to suite
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fn & _
            ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""
    rs.Open "Select `Description`, 0 As Opening From `Sheet2$B2:B` As A " & _
            "Where A.Description Is Not Null And Not Exists (Select `Description` From " & _
            "`Purchase$B2:B` As B In '" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "' 'Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;' " & _
            "Where A.`Description` = B.`Description`);", cn
    Sheets("Purchase").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    Set cn = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```